# How to have a single setUp tearDown for a whole group of JUnit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I want to setup my testing database with test data before I start my tests. I suppose I should run that once at the start of the unit tests instead of before each test class for function? How might I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with [`@SuiteClasses`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.SuiteClasses.html) annotation:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({UserDaoTests.class, OrderDaoTests.class})
public class TestSuiteSetup {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpDatabase() {
        // ...
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownDatabase() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Tests from `UserDaoTests` and `OrderDaoTests` will be run between `setUpDatabase` and `tearDownDatabase` methods.

Comment: If I leave `@RunWith`, I get `Class not found`. If I remove that, I get no tests found, but I have 4 `@Test` in `DataAccessTests`. Please refer to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627434/classnotfoundexception-when-in-junit-suite-setup-class

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution to [How to load DBUnit test data once per case with Spring Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007425/how-to-load-dbunit-test-data-once-per-case-with-spring-test) will do this. It works across an arbitrary set of test cases.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, [TestNG](http://testng.org) supports this with @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite (and many more configuration annotations).