# JUnit 4 - create HSQLDB tables programmatically before running unit tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, junit, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB for unit testing, I have bunch of Test classes which all extends one Abstract class MyAbstractTestBase.

```
class abstract MyAbstractTestBase 
{
   static
   {
      setUpDBTables();
   }

   public static void setUpDBTables()
   {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{
            "file:spring-configuration/unit-testing-config.xml"
        });
        //InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db/MY_TABLE.sql");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)context.getBean("MyDataSource");

        namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

   }
}
```

Major problem with this approach is entityManager created by spring,

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = MyConstants.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_UNIT_NAME)
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

doesn't persist data and no exception is thrown either, but if I try to read some data using "select" it works.

Here is my question, How do I create tables before starting unit-tests? So that my entityManager will work as expected.

Also, why did my entityManager did not persist any record even though it did not throw any exception.

Comment: I'm confused - if you need to create tables to enable you code to run, how are your SELECT statements working?

Comment: 1. I am able to create tables.
2. I am able insert data using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate initialized in abstract class.
3. I am unable to insert/persist data using entitymanager.
4. I can test "select" using entityManager by setting breakpoint and inserting record manually or by using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using spring test, I strongly suggest using the approach from this answer: [How to load DBUnit test data once per case with Spring Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007425/how-to-load-dbunit-test-data-once-per-case-with-spring-test/9006655#9006655)

Comment: Thanks, your answer in the other post is exactly what I was looking. Still, I have one question. When I insert record using entityManager I am not able to query for those records from HSQLDB explorer, whereas using entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * ...") returns result, how come this is possible?