# How to run a method exactly once before/after all tests, regardless of which suite of tests is triggered

Tags: maven, junit

I know that variations of this question have been asked over and over but I can't seem to find a good answer.

I have some integration tests which require a live database that is running to perform the tests.

Since starting up and shutting down the database is costly, I don't want to do this for every single test method. Therefore, I want something that will run before all tests in a test suite, and after all tests in a test suite. It's also important that nested test suites don't run their own before and after methods if the root test suite has already defined these.

So to recap:

1. I want to run a method before and after tests in a test suite are executed.
2. I want to have nested test suites that can be run on their own, or as a larger set of tests and still have these methods called only once.

Does anyone have some good solution for this problem?

Comment: Look in to this page: may be you could find answer for it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580670/testsuite-setup-in-junit-4

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007425/how-to-load-dbunit-test-data-once-per-case-with-spring-test/9006655#9006655

Comment: @Casey: It would help if you could provide details about what from the solutions to other related questions doesn't work for your specific problems. I.e. clarify why this question is not a duplicate of the others.