# How do I share state between JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit

I have a test class extending `junit.framework.TestCase` with several test methods.Each method opens a HTTP connection to server and exchange request and response json strings.One method gets a response with a string called UID(similar to sessionId) which i need to use in subsequent requests to the server.

I was previously writing that string to a file and my next requests read that file for string.I am running one method at a time.Now I am trying to use that string without file operations.I maintained a hastable(because there are many UIDs to keep track of) in my test class as instance variable for the purpose , but eventually found that class is getting loaded for my each method invocation as my static block is executing everytime.This is causing the loss of those UIDs.

How do I achieve this without writing to file and reading from it?

I doubt whether my heading matches my requirement.Someone please edit it accordingly.

Comment: Avoid/minimise use of member variables in test class. Use local variables inside the test methods as much as possible. It will make each test more independent/separate/self-contained
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706008/is-it-a-good-practice-to-share-member-variables-among-unit-tests?rq=3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need a static variable for this because each test gets its own instance of the test class.

Use this pattern:

```
private static String uuid;

private void login() {
    // Run this only once
    if (null != uuid) return;

    ... talk to your server ...
    uuid = responseFromServer.getUuid();
}

@Test
public void testLogin() {
    login();
    assertNotNull( uuid );
}

@Test
public void someOtherTest() {
    login();

    ... test something else which needs uuid ...
}

@Test
public void testWithoutLogin() {
    ... usual test code ...
}
```

This approach makes sure that `login()` is called for each test that needs it, that it's tested on its own and that you can run each test independently.

Answer (score 6):

JUnit will create a new instance of the class for each test. Consequently you should likely set up and store this info as static to the class, using a [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) annotated static method.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3353183/12960) for more info.