# Pass Spring @Value into static @BeforeAll Junit5 method

Tags: java, spring

I have such case, I need to set system properties, before I inject testable class, because this class should be init with this system property for test.

To do this I run setting of system vars in `@BeforeAll` method which is `static` :

```
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;  

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init(){
        System.setProperty("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", "someId");
        System.setProperty("AZURE_TENANT_ID", "someId");
        System.setProperty("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", "someSecret" );
    }
```

And it works perfectly fine.

But now I want to read this property from application.yaml, like :

```
    @Value("clientId")
    private String clientId;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init(){
        System.setProperty("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", clientId);
        System.setProperty("AZURE_TENANT_ID", tenantId);
        System.setProperty("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", someSecret);
    }
```

Problem is that I cannot reference non-static from static method and I definitely need to run `@BeforeAll` first to set System properties.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign a value from application.properties to a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192373/how-to-assign-a-value-from-application-properties-to-a-static-variable) Check also the second answer.

Comment: @Iugiorgi second with PropertyExtractor worked for me

Comment: If you want to know why the @BeforeAll method is static read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052577/why-must-junits-fixturesetup-be-static the first answer. I found it interesting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution proposed in [How to assign a value from application.properties to a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192373/how-to-assign-a-value-from-application-properties-to-a-static-variable) in second answer worked for me. Just added

```
public class PropertiesExtractor {
private static Properties properties;
static {
    properties = new Properties();
    URL url = PropertiesExtractor.class.getClassLoader().getResource("application.properties");
    try{
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(url.getPath()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getProperty(String key){
    return properties.getProperty(key);
}
```

}

And then in my code in static @BeforeAll got all need properties with

```
PropertiesExtractor.getProperty("clientId")
```